# Unable to login to the admin panel in Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2, web-development-server

The site is working fine but when I switch to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ it shows AttributeError at /admin/ .I tried to include MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the mysite/settings.py but to no avail . Here are some details :

Django mysite.settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'personal',
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ page ::

[image]

Django mysite.urls ::

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Am I missing something? Ask for more info if required .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that altering the order of the middlewares can cause serious problems, which it did in your case.

So my advice to you is to add your apps at the end of the `INSTALLED_APPS` and create a new django project and replace your middlewares list with the middlewares list of the newly created project or try with these

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```