# Django admin error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user

Tags: python, django

I am practicing Django, and when i try to go to http://localhost/admin/ i get the below error, I have checked settings.py and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES does exist, is there any other reason why i am getting this message.

```
    AttributeError at /admin/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in has_permission, line 186
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/yasserhussain/learning_site',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 4 Jan 2018 00:17:34 +0000
```

content of MIDDLEWARE in settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087556/unable-to-login-to-the-admin-panel-in-django/48087660#48087660

Answer (score 9):

Django 2.0 has dropped support for old-style middleware classes in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` [changelog, last item](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

Upgrading is straightforward if you use only standard middleware, explained in [Upgrading pre-Django 1.10-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware).
Often just renaming `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to `MIDDLEWARE` and removing `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'` is enough.

You must also make sure [`django.contrib.auth` is installed properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/#installation). In addition to `SessionMiddleware`, which you already have, you should add `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: Thanks @Jieter, i have done as you said above but i still get the same error message :|

Comment: I've updated my answer with a note about adding `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`

Answer (score 2):

My original Django version was 1.9 . I ran into the same issue after upgrading to version 2.0.5. 
Renaming MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE and removing 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware' in settings.py did the job